# How to enable user defined functions in docker instance of cassandra?

Tags: docker, cassandra, cql, udf

Getting the following error when i try to create a simple subtraction function in cassandra:

```
user defined functions are disabled in cassandra.yaml set enable user defined functions=true
```

I can't figure out how to set it to true.  Where do I go to do this?  I am running a docker instance of cassandra which makes it more difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to modify the cassandra.yaml file within your Dockerfile.
You could create a separate layer as an extension of your original Cassandra image (more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)).

Assuming you are using Cassandra 3, and that you installed from the package installation, its location is:

```
/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Other possible locations for different installation options (tarball, etc.) are documented [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html?hl=cassandra.yaml). If you are running [this](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/e80c6550afd16ead245ec73b16862984480a7cf9/3.0/Dockerfile) Docker image, you should probably find it in */etc/cassandra*.

Once you figure out the path for the installation, you could use sed to change the file in place. Run it with Docker's RUN command:

```
RUN sed -i -r 's/enable_user_defined_functions=false/enable_user_defined_functions=true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Then restart a node.

Comment: I had to use below command. `RUN sed -i -r 's/enable_user_defined_functions: false/enable_user_defined_functions: true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`

Comment: hi @edmon, I tried your proposed solution, 
```winpty docker-compose exec cassandradb sh -c "sed -i -r 's/enable_user_defined_functions: false/enable_user_defined_functions: true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml";```

Also restarted the service, but still my scripts are still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 6):

In your `docker-compose.yaml` file, add the following under your environment:

```
environment:
    - CASSANDRA_ENABLE_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTIONS=true
```

Then, modify `docker-entrypoint.sh` (you can get it from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/064fb4e2682bf9c1909e4cb27225fa74862c9086/3.11/docker-entrypoint.sh)), and add 
`enable_user_defined_functions`

```
for yaml in \
        broadcast_address \
        broadcast_rpc_address \
        cluster_name \
        endpoint_snitch \
        listen_address \
        num_tokens \
        rpc_address \
        start_rpc \
        enable_user_defined_functions \
```

Also, You will need to override the docker-entrypoint.sh with the modified version:

```
volumes:
- ./db/Cassandra/docker-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Use the latest one: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/cassandra/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

The one linked in the answer won't work with the latest Docker image for Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Based to @Edmon's accepted answer and related @Ravi's comment I enabled user defined functions at my example "cassandra 3.11" docker instance and run tested successfully. I post this answer as an applied example like mini tutorial.

## Reproduce steps

Prequesties

- in a new project folder there should be these 2 files: `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`

  ```
  cassandra-udf-demo-folder
  │   docker-compose.yml
  │   Dockerfile
  ```
- having docker installed, I am using [Docker Desktop 4.12.0](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4120)

1. "docker-compose.yml" file contents

```
   # docker-compose.yml

   version: '3'
   services:
     n1:
      build: .
      image: cassandra:3.11
      networks:
        - cluster
   networks:
   cluster:
```

2. "Dockerfile" file contents

```
   # Dockerfile

   FROM cassandra:3.11
   # override default disabled user defined functions
   RUN sed -i -r 's/enable_user_defined_functions: false/enable_user_defined_functions: true/' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

3. Rebuild image, then recreate corresponding service's container and run in the background based to provided Dockerfile + docker-compose.yml files.

```
   ~ docker-compose up --build -d
```

4. Check if user defined functions have been enabled, default is false

```
   ~ docker-compose exec -it n1 egrep "enable_user_defined_functions" /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

   enable_user_defined_functions: true
   # Java UDFs are always enabled, if enable_user_defined_functions is true.
   # This option has no effect, if enable_user_defined_functions is false.
```

5. Connect to cassandra node and interact with cassandra

> cqlsh is a command-line interface for interacting with Cassandra using CQL (the Cassandra Query Language)

```
   docker-compose exec n1 cqlsh

   Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
   [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.14 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
   Use HELP for help.
   cqlsh>
```

6. Now we are inside cassandra cli. We will create a keyspace & a table inside this keyspace populated with test data

```
   // create keyspace
   create keyspace foo 
   WITH replication = {
   'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 
   'replication_factor': 1};

   // use keyspace
   use foo;

   // create table data for our udf demo
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA 
       (
       id int,
       num1 int,
       num2 int,
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
       );

   // insert table rows for our udf demo
   INSERT INTO 
   UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA(id, num1, num2) 
   VALUES(1, 400, 600);

   INSERT INTO 
   UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA(id, num1, num2) 
   VALUES(2, 500, 400);

   INSERT INTO 
   UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA(id, num2) 
   VALUES(3, 900);

   INSERT INTO 
   UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA(id, num1) 
   VALUES(4, 500);

   // overview our table
   SELECT * 
   FROM UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA
   WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4);

    id | num1 | num2
   ----+------+------
     1 |  400 |  600
     2 |  500 |  400
     3 | null |  900
     4 |  500 | null
```

7. Now remaining at cassandra cli, we will create a user defined function using java, that returns the max of 2 given numbers. If any null found returns null

```
   // our user defined function "MAX_VALUE"
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAX_VALUE (num1 int, num2 int)
       RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
       RETURNS int
       LANGUAGE java
       AS $$ 
       return Math.max(num1, num2); 
       $$;

   // overview our table 
   // appending results 
   with max number from our udf function
   SELECT 
   id, num1, num2, MAX_VALUE(num1, num2) 
   FROM UDF_FUNCTION_TEST_DATA
   WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4);

    id | num1 | num2 | foo.max_value(num1, num2)
   ----+------+------+---------------------------
     1 |  400 |  600 |                       600
     2 |  500 |  400 |                       500
     3 | null |  900 |                      null
     4 |  500 | null |                      null

     // now that we tested udf successfully,
     // we can exit cqlsh
     exit
```

8. Stop and remove containers, networks

```
   ~ docker-compose down
```